# Using 5 of letter S and 3 of letter W, how many distinct words can we write?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Using 5 of letter S and 3 of letter W, how many distinct words can we write? We will use all the letters, that is, each word will be of eight letters.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: How many ways can you pick three objects out of eight?

Comment: What Andrew Chin is hinting at is that the word is completely determined by choosing in which three of the eight positions a W appears since the remaining positions will be filled with S's.

Comment: In case the other comments are not heavy handed enough of a hint... the correct search term in your textbook or around the internet is [Binomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  This is exactly the type of scenario that binomial coefficients are commonly used for (*though they have many more uses beyond this*).

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints/comments. So, it is 8P3.

Answer (score 0):

You have $8$ spots and you want to fill up those spots with $5$ ,$S$ and $3$ ,$W$

Well if you choose $5$ out of $8$ for your $S$ then you are done.

Thus the answer is $\binom {8}{5}=56$